# java Wicket herokuapp too slow?

Tags: java, web, heroku, wicket

I made a simple wicket app but it has very slow response times on heroku (1-3s) when using AjaxSubmitLink. Changig pages with BookmarkablePageLinks is fast however? Something wrong with appending javascript? Why is it so slow?

```
class JumpToButton extends AjaxSubmitLink{
        String markupId;
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            super.onSubmit(target);
            target.appendJavaScript("$([document.documentElement, document.body])"
                    + ".animate({"
                    + "scrollTop: $('#"+markupId+"').offset().top"
                    + "    }, 400);");
        }

        public TabButton(String id, String markupId) {
            super(id);
            this.markupId = markupId;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you benchmark your solution to diagnose this slowness? Is the slowness client-side (JavaScript), server-side (Wicket or the servlet container?) or a combination of both?

Comment: I dont know how to find that out. It works fine on localhost and other wicket actions and javascript seem to work fine. Appending javascript is slow

Comment: I don't expect the appending itself to be slow, but to find out you could do something like `long start = System.nanoTime();` prior to `target.appendJavaScript` and something like `log.info("Execution of appendJavascript took {} nanoseconds", System.nanoTime() - start);` after it (don't forget to declare `log` though)

Comment: yes appending itself wasn't the issue. Maybe the issue is on the server side since I logged the time between repeated onSubmit() calls and that was way slower on heroku.